# Return new promise in a function vs using new promise directly in async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

When I create 3 different promises using this function:

```
const setTimer = (num) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(num)
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

and then run them inside async/await function:

```
const func = async () => {
  const first = await setTimer(1)
  console.log(first);
  const second = await setTimer(2)
  console.log(second);
  const third = await setTimer(3)
  console.log(third);
}

func()
```

They run synchronously (one after each other) as expected.

Then I create 3 different promises using new promise directly:

```
const setTimer1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(1)
  }, 2000);
})

const setTimer2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(2)
  }, 2000);
})

const setTimer3 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(3)
  }, 2000);
})
```

And then run those 3 promises again in async/await function:

```
const func1 = async () => {
  const first = await setTimer1
  console.log(first);
  const second = await setTimer2
  console.log(second);
  const third = await setTimer3
  console.log(third);
}

func1()
```

They now run asynchronously (in parallel). Please help explain why. I have searched for really long but have not found the answer.

Comment: _"They now run asynchronously (in parallel)"_ - no. they run in sequence; one after the other. Difference in both code examples is the first one creates a promise inside a function.

Comment: The promises "start" when instantiated, not when first awaited. Your first snippet instantiates a promise only once the previous one is completed. Your second snippet instantiates them all then awaits them.

Comment: `setTimer()` creates a `Promise` when called. `const setTimerX = new Promise()` creates the promise immediately.

Comment: As others said, Promises start when created, so in your case they finish at the same time (even though sequentially). Try setting one to 2000, another one to 3000 and the last one to 4000 - you will see the difference :)

Comment: @OldGeezer where? In `setTimeout()` or in ` new Promise()`? Because both of these return values are rejected and do nothing.

Comment: @RoboRobok My hasty mistake. Have deleted it to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @sp00m Thanks. But I'm still confused why in the first case, it waits until the previous has completed after 2 secs. While in second case, they all instantiate at the same time without waiting 2 secs?

Comment: @kevinV but they are waiting 2 seconds in the second example!

Comment: "synchronously" ≠ "sequentially". They are different concepts.

Comment: In the two cases, ask youself "at what point do the timers start running?" If you successfully answer that question, then you will have solved your dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to understand the difference by comparing the following examples:

```js
(async () => {
    const p1 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    const p2 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    const p3 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

    await p1;
    console.log(1); // 2 seconds later
    await p2;
    console.log(2); // 0 seconds later
    await p3;
    console.log(3); // 0 seconds later
})();
```

All Promises are created immediately one after another, so at the time when the first one is ready, all of them are. That's why you will get `1`, `2` and `3` in your console at the same time.

But now consider this example:

```js
(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log(1); // 2 seconds later
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log(2); // 2 seconds later
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log(3); // 2 seconds later
})();
```

This time, the second Promise gets instantiated after the first one is resolved, so after 2 seconds. Same goes with the third one waiting for the second one. And this is why you will get `1` after 2 seconds, `2` after another 2 seconds and `3` after yet another 2 seconds.

To understand why, it's enough to know that the Promise tries to be as fast as possible. It starts its job as soon as it's created. And that's a good thing!

Answer (score 1):

Your latter three declarations are not functions. They assign each a promise that runs the moment each is created. So, they should be coded like your first, where the promise is created only when the function is invoked:

```
const setTimer1 = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(1)
  }, 2000);
})

const setTimer2 = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(2)
  }, 2000);
})

const setTimer3 = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res(3)
  }, 2000);
})
```

Then you need to invoke each function:

```
const func1 = async () => {
  const first = await setTimer1();
  console.log(first);
  const second = await setTimer2();
  console.log(second);
  const third = await setTimer3();
  console.log(third);
}

func1()
```

The required changes are very *subtle*, adding only a few characters. Compare with your code to see the differences.